# What is the difference between square brackets and test command on bash?

Tags: bash, test

Single square brackets `[` and `test`command both are built in the bash shell.

Why are there two separate commands if both square brackets `[` and `test` commands have the same function?

Comment: I think they are equivalent as specified in [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`[` and `test` are the same command. Only, `[` expects its last argument to be `]` (which it otherwise ignores).

The `[` and `test` command are often implemented by the same binary file. Most Bourne-like shells and `fish` have both `[` and `test` builtin. The C shell or `rc` and their derivatives don't. The C shell has dedicated constructs to perform some of the operations normally performed by the `test`/`[` utility.

The `test` command appeared in Unix V7 in the late 70s alongside the then new Bourne shell. Previous versions had no `test` command, and their shell didn't have a `if` construct. But there was a [standalone `if` command](http://man.cat-v.org/unix-6th/1/if) that could do a few of the same tests that `test` does and execute a command depending on the result.

The Bourne shell introduced a few control statements (`if`/`while`/`until`), so `test` was introduced to complement that, to have a command which could be used in the condition part of those statements to perform various tests.

There was no `[` command in V7, but you can find some [unfinished](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/blob/Research-V7-Snapshot-Development/usr/src/cmd/sh/msg.c#L114) [commented out code](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/blob/Research-V7-Snapshot-Development/usr/src/cmd/sh/xec.c#L165) in there for a `[` builtin suggesting they had already envisioned it by then, but probably decided against cluttering the `sh` code with it at the time.

`[` and `test` builtins were added to the Bourne shell [in System III in 1981](https://www.in-ulm.de/%7Emascheck/bourne/#system3).

All Bourne-like shells including `bash` have had a `[`/`test` builtin since then, but note that while the Almquist shell had `[`/`test` built-in from the start (actually merged with `expr`), it was initially disabled (not compiled in) in early BSDs and until quite late in some.

Both `[` and `test` are [standard POSIX commands](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html). They are not required to be builtin, but they are required to be executable from things like `env`, `find -exec`, `execvp()`, etc, so be available as standalone executable.

You still find some systems though that supply a standalone `test` utility but not a `[` one. Which explains why you see more often things like:

```
find . -exec test -f {} ';'
```

(equivalent of GNU `find`'s `-xtype f`), than:

```
find . -exec [ -f {} ] ';'
```

Which would fail on systems that don't supply a standalone `[` utility.

As another anecdotal difference between `[` and `test`, since `test <any-string>` (same as `[ <any-string> ]`) is a valid test which tests whether `<any-string>` is non-empty, `test --version` or `test --help` cannot return the version of `test` or its usage. `[ --version` however is not a valid test, so you'll find that the GNU standalone `[` utility accepts `--version` and `--help` to return version and usage information respectively, instead of the usual `missing ‘]’` error message while GNU `test` doesn't (see [corresponding commit from 2003](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/commit/?h=9fed987cf27c75e141a9fe3dac1ca4923ea48b6d) (misleading comment [fixed in 2005](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/commit/?h=843efb8e3b551bd2d70945371b1c5df946ab1f4d))).

```
$ '/usr/bin/[' --version
[ (GNU coreutils) 8.30
[...]
$ /usr/bin/test --version && echo "--version is non-empty"
--version is non-empty
$ '/usr/bin/[' --something-else
/usr/bin/[: missing ‘]’
```

Comment: thanks for referencing that commit from 1979!